# How to store Boolean values for later use

Tags: xparse, etoolbox, latex-base

I want to define a new command for a package using `xparse`. My command looks like this:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\fancyCommand}{s o m}{
    \def\@optional{#2}
    \def\@mandatory{#3}
}
```

This is, because I need the mandatory and optional arguments for later use. I also want to have the Boolean value of `#1`. How can I store this value? I tried constructions via `\newif` and `\newtoggl` with the `etoolbox` package, but both ways throw an error `Undefined control sequence.`

Comment: just store #1 and test with `\IfBooleanTF`  you don't need `xparse`  unless you have an old latex, you don't need `etoolbox` for this at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried just that, but then I get the error `Use of \??? doesn't match its definition.`

Comment: By the way, this is the first time I try to write a package. Googling for "latex boolean" I just find the information about `\newif`.

Comment: the tests for star and optional arguments generated by `\NewDocumentCommand` do not use `\newif` based commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note these commands are in latex by default, `xparse` is only needed in older formats. Suitable tests are provided, you do not need additional packages.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\fancyCommand}{s o m}{%
    \let\@star#1%
    \def\@optional{#2}%
    \def\@mandatory{#3}%
}

\def\test{%
The last command
\IfBooleanTF\@star{had a star}{did not have a star},
\ExpandArgs{o}\IfNoValueTF\@optional{no option}{option: \@optional},
argument: \@mandatory.}


\makeatother
\begin{document}

\fancyCommand{aaa} \test

\fancyCommand*[jj]{bbb} \test

\fancyCommand*{ccc} \test


\end{document}
```

Comment: Note this answers the question as asked, but it would be more idiomatic to do the tests in `\fancyCommand` and define "real" values to pick up later rather than saving the raw option parsing tokens, but this is possible for cases where you need it

Comment: I still get the `Use of \??? doesn't match its definition.` error. What do you mean with "real values".

EDIT: Maybe I should close the question and search for another approach to my goal.

Comment: @Matthias You get an error from the code in my answer? which latex release do you have? By  real values I mean instead of `\def\@optional{#2}%` which may leave `\@optional` with the magic `--novalue--` marker, do `\IfNoValueTF{\def\@length{\textwidth}}{\def\@length{#2}}` or whatever you want to do in your main function then afterwards you can use `\@length` without having to repeat the parsing `\IfNoValueTF` tests on `*` and `[` forms.  (It's annoying if people delete questions that are answered, someone may find the answer useful even if you decide a different path :-)

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear in my comment. Your code works just fine, but when I  apply your solution to my code (my command is very simply to your code) I get the error. I am working in Overleaf with Tex Live Version 2022, pdfLatex. I will work out a MWE.

Comment: I think I found the mistake(s): 1) `\let\@star{#1}` instead of `\let\@star#1` throws an error `Too many }'s`. 2) Since I use the information of `\@star` in the class, I must use `\AtBeginnDocument{}` so that the one can use `\fancyCommand` in the preamble and therefore set the variable `\@star`.

Comment: @Matthias `\let\@star{` defines `\@star` to be `{`